# first batch, bucket lid is bulging

Tags: fermenter

I mixed my first batch about 7 hours ago.  I was told to put the mix and sugar into this bucket then in a week transfer it into the secondary fermenter.

I just walked by and see the lid on the bucket is very bulged out and I'm concerned it'll blow!

Picture: [image: Bulging bucket]

Comment: As as immediate solution before you install an airlock (as demonstrated in the answers), I'd recommend cracking the lid ever so slightly on one side.  This may expose it just enough to infect it, but it's better infected than exploded all over your walls/ceiling/floor.  Trust me.

Comment: ... By cracking, I of course mean opening the lid just a little bit to let the pressure out (just wanted to clarify so that you don't take it too literally).  You can seal it back up again, just so long as you let the pressure out every couple of hours.

Comment: Yes I agree with @Scott I should have included that in the answer. Slightly lift the lid of the barrel to release pressure then reseal it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it might help to know what you are brewing.

I can't see an airlock on the bucket so depending on what you are brewing you may have to add an airlock so the CO2 can escape the barrel. This would stop it blowing up!!!

Again without knowing what you are brewing it is hard to give any advice.

If you want to know more about airlocks take a look at this video. [CraigTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4WMc0xDbEbo)

Comment: Brewing a muntons irish stout.

Comment: Do you have an airlock on the fermenter? If not then that is your problem. I would recommend checking out the video I put in the answer and it will teach you about air locks.

Comment: No air lock.  Bought everything from the local brew supply store. The pail had no opening for it,  and they said nothing about making an opening. Hopefully just relieving pressure is good for the next while until I can modify the pail

Comment: Ok I would follow Scotts suggestion until you can buy an airlock and fit it. While your at it have a go at the guy at the home brew store and ask why they didn't tell you that you needed one

Comment: I have one.  But it was for the secondary. I just need time to modify the lid and re-sterilize it. Which brings up another question.  What's the easiest way to sterilize. The packet of stuff they gave me is used up.

Comment: buy yourself some "Star San" and pH strips (that can read below 2 pH) at your homebrew store, as well as a spray bottle if you don't have one. fill the spray bottle with water, throw in a tbsp of star san into the bottle, and test the pH of it.  If it's above 3, add another tbsp, and another until you are below 3 pH.  Then spray down your lid, and anything else.  Spray bottle administered Star San is a sure-fire solution for sanitation.  If not Star San, submerge it in a bleach solution and rinse thoroughly.

Comment: Again @Scott beat me to it. Sterilizing is a very important step of home brewing. You cant go half assed with it. I don't use Star san but Sodium Metabisulphite to sterilize and another solution to clean with. Mainly because star san is newly imported from where I live. I would use it if it was the same cost as my other cleaners. Buy yourself a book or again watch CraigTube for some tips on cleaning. I'm sure he has a video on cleaning

Comment: @CaffGeek - The airlock is definitely for primary fermentation since that's when most of the carbon dioxide is produced.

Comment: @CaffGeek how did you go with installing the airlock? Did you manage to get it sorted before a blow out?

Comment: @WillNZ, I drilled a hole in the lid, and added the airlock.  Just transfered into the secondary this weekend (probably a little later than I should have)

Answer (score 0):

You need an air lock to let out the gas. When making beer you're essentially creating a batch of yeast food- gas (CO2) and alcohol are the yeast "poop". You need to give that gas somewhere to go.